# Relational data query in Parse - retrieve users with and without messages

Tags: parse-platform

I have a relation on user in Parse 'messages'

I want to issue a query via cloudcoud that retrieves all friends of user (another relation, friendship) AND messages if there are any messages where the current user is the recipient.

I got this far:

```
var relation = current.relation("friendship");
var queryRel = relation.query(); 
queryRel.select("username","color","count");
queryRel.ascending("username");

var innerQuery = new Parse.Query("Message");
innerQuery.equalTo("recipient",current);

queryRel.matchesQuery("messages", innerQuery);
```

...but that only retrieves friends of the current user who have messages, not those who are friends but don't have messages. I need both!

If at all possible, I also want to retrieve the messages themselves, not just pointers. This is all so I can return properly organised data to the client so my apps don't have to do lots of looping to sort things.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `include` method here. The way it works is you would do `queryRel.include("message");` so you won't just get the pointers. I believe you should also remove the second query for this to work.

The above code is assuming your column pointing to the Message table is called "message"